# Sharing For Facebook Messenger Not Working In Gmail

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, gmail

I have to provide a hyperlink in email (this will be sent via Gmail) which will open FB Messenger by default with some default message text in all platforms (Android, iOS, Web). I did not find anything regarding that but FB provides an option share a URL in Messenger as hyperlink.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger

```
<a href=”fb-messenger://share/?link= https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fsharing%2Freference%2Fsend-dialog&app_id=123456789”>Send In Messenger</a>
```

But this also did not work. Gmail is not sending the text **"Send In Messenger"** as a hyperlink but sending it as plain text.

Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944105/send-link-with-custom-scheme-through-gmail this might help you

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)